# How is the adverb "even" used here differently?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases

[Source](http://epaperbeta.timesofindia.com/Article.aspx?eid=31808&articlexml=For-Modi-its-a-vindication-after-US-visa-30042016019069)

> It isn't just the Arabic-speaking man or the hijab-clad woman who were off-loaded from airplanes; **even in** pure, white, nativist America, there is an uptick in the kind of religious fundamentalism that India is often harangued for.

The two sentences are different in the intentions.I felt it awkward like:

*It isn't that he just dances; even she sings.*

The first sentence talks about offloading and the second one of an uptick in the religions.

Comment: The *semantics* of the first clause boil down to *religious fundamentalism isn't only visible in discriminatory airport security* (in which context the relevant religion is *Islam*). The second clause contrasts this with an increase in *Christian* "fundamentalism", far removed from the "cultural interface" represented by airports (which manifests ***even*** in "middle-class suburban America", where radicalized Muslims and terrorist threats are virtually non-existent). It's a little "laboured", but I'd say it's perfectly valid phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even** often means "also, contrary to what you might expect".

> He plays golf every day, even on his wife's birthday.

It reveals the speaker's/author's sense of what is generally expected. The speaker of the above sentence believes that it is somewhat unusual for a man to play golf on his wife's birthday.